# Angular equivalent of Knockout ko.dataFor

Tags: angularjs

`ko.dataFor(element)` allows to retrieve the object bound to a DOM element. Does angular have a similar function?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? its better if you provide a code sample of your angularjs

Comment: For example if I click on an element, I want to access the object which is responsible for rendering that element. I could use ngClick, but it feels like I'm repeating myself a lot. I'd like to create a directive on the parent, in the directive, bind click events to the children, then update my scope with the selected object.

Comment: it seems like your on the right path with creating a directive... without providing some code its a bit hard to see what the issue is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
angular.element(element1).scope().variable
```

element1: dom element,
variable: scope variable

More information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

Comment: This is the correct answer. angular.element(node).scope() is exactly the same as ko.dataFor(node).

I often use this in Chrome Dev Tools. If you inspect an element, that element will be bound to $0 in the console. angular.element($0).scope() will then give you the scope for the inspected element.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS have a different approach on that and data is not strictly bounded to DOM elements, You probably can look up for two way data binding that will bring you closer to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind data to DOM elements in the first place. Store data in for example angular services.